# What lies between primitive recursion and total recursion?

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

My understanding is that there are [total recursive functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language) that are not [primitive recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function), such as the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). What classes of functions (or sets) lie between primitive recursion and total recursion, that include and exclude the Ackermann function?

Comment: The hierarchy between primitive recursive and $\mu$-recursive was thoroughly explored by Rozsa Peter, in the book *Recursive Functions*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive recursive functions are a 'recursively enumerable' (listable) subset of the total recursive functions, which in turn are a subset of the partial recursive functions. So the memberships look like:

Primitive recursive $ \subset $ total recursive $ \subset $ partial recursive

Finding a recursively enumerable list of total recursive functions which contains the set of primitive recursive functions as a proper subset can be easily done using diagonalization:

Suppose we have a recursively enumerable list $S=f_1, f_2, ..., f_n,... $ of all primitive recursive functions.  Because the primitive recursive functions are total, we know the output of each $f_n(x)$ will always be defined for all $x \in N $. Define the following diagonal function $d(x)=f_x(x)+1 $ for all $x \in N$. Obviously this function is not primitive recursive: if we let $d$ be in our original list $S$, i.e. $d=f_e$ for some natural number $e$, then we'd have $d(e)=f_e(e)=f_e(e)+1 $ which implies $0=1$ (a contradiction).  Because each $f_n$ is primitive recursive and defined for all natural numbers $n$, and because adding 1 is obviously recursive, this implies $d$ is a total recursive function that is not primitive recursive.

The following is a recursively enumerable list of total recursive functions which contains the primitive recursive functions as a proper subset.

$S' = d,f_1, f_2, ..., f_n,...  $

The memberships would look like:

$S$ (primitive recursive) $ \subset  S'  \subset $ total recursive $ \subset $ partial recursive

This process could be repeated by renaming the recursively enumerable members of $S'$ as $S'=f'_1, f'_2, ... f'_n,...$ to reveal $ S''$ and repeated further to reveal $ S'''$ and $ S''''$ such that we'd have:

$S$ (primitive recursive) $ \subset  S'   \subset  S''   \subset  S'''   \subset  S''''  \subset $ total recursive $ \subset $ partial recursive

There is much more to be said about all this, but I figured I'd give you a little teaser.

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll take a closer look. Is there a specific place in this hierarchy where e.g. the Ackermann function would be in?

Comment: Here is a good post regarding a related question: [Between mu- and primitive recursion](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46350/between-mu-and-primitive-recursion)